# mpf_set_d causes an illegal instruction in c++

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin, gmp

I'm using GMP and getting an illegal instruction that I have found to be caused by mpf_set_d. I'm programming in Netbeans with cygwin in c++.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I have a folder containing the following files:
.dep.inc, cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll, cyggmp-10.dll, cyggmpxx-4.dll, cygstdc++-6.dll, cygwin1.dll, my executable, gmp.h, gmpxx.h, libgmp.a, libgmp.la, libgmp.lai, libgmp.lai, libgmp.libcmd, libgmpxx.a, libgmpxx.la, libgmpxx.lai, main.cpp, main.o, main.o.d, Makefile, text file needed for program and folders needed for program.

I have tried many things, one of which was to add an executable to this folder that ran the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "gmpxx.h"
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mpf_t a;
    mpf_init(a);
    mpf_set_d(a,3.1415926535);
    cout << "works" << endl;
}
```

Running this on my own computer with GMP installed gives me 'works' after which it closes, on another computer that does not have GMP installed it throws an error and closes. The error is an exception: status_illegal_instruction.

I can't give you my code but I can post snippets. Please tell me if more information is necessary!

Thanks again.

Edit 2:

The same counts for mpf_set_str as well as the c++ wrapper.

Comment: We aren't psychic -- we need *much* more detail on this issue...

Comment: I'm sorry @LThode I'll edit the first post. Thanks for your response, though!